# Clojure - map values

Tags: clojure

I'm trying get a clojure function to detect if the value passed is a map.
For example,

```
user=> (if-map {:foo 1}) ;Should return true
true 
user=> (if-map "hello") ;Returns false
false
```

Is there a pre-built function serving this already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`map?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map_q) is the inbuilt function

```
(map? {:a 1})
=> true

(map? [1])
=> false
```

Comment: conj.io looks like a great resource. would indeed be helpful! :)

Comment: Up to a point, Lord Copper: `(map? x)` returns whether `x` implements `IPersistentMap`. It could be something other than a `clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap` or other built-in map implementation. But it is what you ought to want to know: Clojure is built around interfaces, not specific implementations.

Comment: umm. yeah. i guess. she asked for checking a standard clojure map. in clojure. as per tag `clojure`, and as per the question "Clojure - map values", so i'm not getting your point here. does your comment add anything here? if there's an issue with my answer, please provide a better one